# Field generated and fraction field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Given a field extension $K/F$, $\alpha \in K$, why is it the case that $F(\alpha)$, i.e. the subfield of K generated by $\alpha$, is isomorphic to the fraction field of $F[\alpha]$?

My understanding is that as $F[\alpha]$ is the smallest subring that contains $\alpha$, and to make it into a field, we take the ratios. And somehow, this makes it the smallest subfield of $K$ that contains $\alpha$. I can't construct a proper proof for this and is driving me crazy.

Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Maybe think about $F[\alpha, \alpha^{-1}]$ and its relation with $F(\alpha)$. Also, what can you say about $F[\alpha, \alpha^{-1}]$ and the fraction field of $F[\alpha]$.

Comment: I don't really have time to turn this into an answer right now, but you may want to look into the universal property of the field of fractions, if you haven't already. You can see an explanation [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Universal_Property_for_Quotient_Field). It might be overkill in this case, but if you can understand the universal property it should be clear why $F(\alpha)$ has to be the field of fractions, since $F(\alpha)$ is by definition the smallest field containing $F$ and $\alpha$, and therefore the smallest field containing $F[\alpha]$.